# Start a Java GUI app without spawning the console window

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, java

I have an app (DavMail to be precise) which I start from a *.bat file. The command line is

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp davmail.jar davmail.DavGateway options
```

This runs fine, but leaves the console window open for as long as DavMail runs. Is it possible to get rid of it?

I have tried to create a shortcut instead of a bat file. The console still appears (though now it is completely empty), so this didn't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have already written this question when I found the (quite obvious) solution: use `javaw` instead of `java`. The former doesn't have a console window, and the one from `cmd.exe` can be eliminated using `start`:

```
start javaw -Xmx1024m -cp davmail.jar davmail.DavGateway options
```

Comment: Close the question by marking this as the answer :)